# HTML Data-Effect to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, class

I'm currently using this HTML snippet for my Navigation menu. The data-effect attribute in the  tag (data-effect="st-effect-12") activates the transitions to open the navigation menu.

I want to change this to jQuery. so the jQuery will handle the  click. Which will then toggle the st-effect-id CSS element.

I tried the ToggleClass argument but I couldn't get it to work.

Thanks
Harry!

```css
.st-effect-12.st-container {
  -webkit-perspective: 1500px;
  perspective: 1500px;
}
.st-effect-12 .st-pusher {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.st-effect-12.st-menu-open .st-pusher {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-10deg);
  transform: rotateY(-10deg);
}
.st-effect-12.st-menu {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}
.st-effect-12.st-menu-open .st-effect-12.st-menu {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.st-effect-12.st-menu::after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button data-effect="st-effect-12" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
</button>
```

Thankyou in advance!

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. You need to post a complete code example.

Comment: It sounds like you need toggleClass of jquery. http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic implementation using [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/):

```js
$('button').on('click', function () {
    var button = $(this);
    button.toggleClass(button.data('effect'));
});
```

```css
button {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 56px;
}
button.st-effect-12 {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<button data-effect="st-effect-12"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: is the (button.data('effect')) where the class will be toggled?

Comment: `button.data('effect')` takes the value of `data-effect="st-effect-12"` and `button.toggleClass()` adds it is it's missing or removes it if it is present.

Answer (score 0):

Well in your case you should use id or class for jquery

HTML

```
 <button data-effect="st-effect-12" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 56px;"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x" id="clickme"></i></button>
```

CSS

```
 .activate{
   background-color:red;
 }
```

JS

```
$('#clickme).click(function(){
 $(this).addClass('activate');
},function(){
 $(this).removeClass('activate');
});
```

i can't test this right now but may b it works for you..